# Running My Android SyncAdapter Immediately.

Tags: android

I've implemented a SyncAdapter pretty much as outlined here (with a dummy account) and using one of my content providers (I have one per table).  As far as I can tell the sync code is fine.  If I go into "Settings -> Accounts" select the dummy account I've created and then the "Sync Now" menu item my adapter is run by the system.  All it does ATM is log the fact that it was called.

But trying to run it from my own "Sync Now" menu option (see below on my main activity) doesn't.  Is there a way of getting the sync adapter to run immediately given that we have a WiFi connection?

> ```
> private boolean actionSynchronize() {
>     if (mLogger.isTraceEnabled())
>         mLogger.trace("Synchronising now!");
>
>     // Pass the settings flags by inserting them in a bundle
>     Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
>     settingsBundle.putBoolean(
>             ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
>     settingsBundle.putBoolean(
>             ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
>     /*
>      * Request the sync for the default account, authority, and
>      * manual sync settings
>      */
>     ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    // Disable sync backoff and ignore sync preferences. In other words...perform sync NOW!
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(
            GenericAccountService.GetAccount(),      // Sync account
            FeedContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, // Content authority
            b);                                      // Extras
```